# API images cannot be converted to blob or base64 data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a website, it has an API image in it I'm trying to convert it to blob, but it doesn't work, is there any solution for the code below

```
fetch("https://t0.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,URL&url=https://stackoverflow.com/&size=64").then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(blobImage) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobImage);
  image.src = objectURL;
});
```

Please provide a solution for the above code, I really need it

Answer (score 0):

Odds are it's probably a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue preventing your browser from loading the image since `t0.gstatic.com` doesn't return an [Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header, meaning you can't fetch it directly using your browser's JS API (though, you may be able to set up a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) that fetches it for you or adds the CORS Allow-Origin header)